# Замена Union в лабе

Tags: visual-c++

Нужно раскрыть функцию union, если конкретно, то заменить участок кода, в котором происходит объединение множеств через функцию union, на кусок кода, в котором происходит объединение множество без функции union, а только через if и подобные операции... Помогите, это реализовать..

Кусок кода, что нужно переделать:

```
void TIntset::Ob(TIntset &K)
{ vector<int> v(N+5);                
  vector<int>::iterator it; //Иттератор - интерфейс, предоставляющий доступ к элементам массива
  sort (M,M+N);     
  sort (K.M,K.M+5);  
  it=set_union(M, M+N, K.M, K.M+5, v.begin());  
  v.resize(it-v.begin());    
  cout << "\nВсего " << (v.size()) << " элементов:\n";
  for (it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
  cout << ' ' << *it;
  cout << '\n';}
```

Весь код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale>
#include <algorithm>   
#include <vector>  
using namespace std;

class TIntset
{int *M;
int N;
int k;
public: //Модификатор доступа - доступ открыт всем, кто видит определение данного класса.
    //Конструктор по умолчанию
    TIntset():M(0),N(0),k(0){}
    //Конструктор с параметром
    TIntset(int k)
    {int i;
    M=new int[k];
    N=k;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {M[i]=rand()%101;}
    }
    //Конструктор копирования
    TIntset(const TIntset& K)
    {int i;
    N=K.N;
    M=new int[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {M[i]=K.M[i];}
    }

    void Input();
    void Output();
    void Rav(TIntset &);
    void Ob(TIntset &);
    };

void TIntset::Input()
{int i;
cout<<"Введите максимальное число элементов множества:\n";
cin>>N;
M=new int[N];
cout<<"\nВведите "<<N<<" элемент(ов) множества:\n";
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
cout<<"["<<i<<"]:";
cin>>M[i];
}
}

void TIntset::Output()
{   cout<<"\nМножество:";
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    cout<<"\n["<<i<<"]"<<M[i];
}

void TIntset::Rav(TIntset &K)
{bool P=true;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if((M[i]==K.M[i])&&(M[i]==K.M[i])){}
        else
        {P=false;}
    }
    if (P==false)
    {cout<<" не равны.";}
    else {cout<<" равны!";}
}

void TIntset::Ob(TIntset &K)
{ vector<int> v(N+5);                
  vector<int>::iterator it; //Иттератор - интерфейс, предоставляющий доступ к элементам массива
  sort (M,M+N);     
  sort (K.M,K.M+5);  
  it=set_union(M, M+N, K.M, K.M+5, v.begin());  
  v.resize(it-v.begin());    
  cout << "\nВсего " << (v.size()) << " элементов:\n";
  for (it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
  cout << ' ' << *it;
  cout << '\n';}

void main()
{
locale L(locale());
locale::global(locale("rus"));
srand((unsigned) time(0));
TIntset A, //По умолчанию
    B(5), //С параметрами
    C(B); //Копирования
A.Input();
A.Output();
B.Output();
C.Output();
cout<<"\nМножества A и B";
A.Rav(B);
cout<<"\nМножества A и C";
A.Rav(C);
cout<<"\nМножества B и C";
B.Rav(C);
A.Ob(B);
B.Ob(C);
A.Ob(C);
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Берем и пишем свой `set_union` - это же в рамках ограничений? :)

Например, так:

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt set_union(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                   InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                   OutputIt d_first)
{
    for (; first1 != last1; ++d_first) {
        if (first2 == last2)
            return std::copy(first1, last1, d_first);
        if (*first2 < *first1) {
            *d_first = *first2++;
        } else {
            *d_first = *first1;
            if (!(*first1 < *first2))
                ++first2;
            ++first1;
        }
    }
    return std::copy(first2, last2, d_first);
}
```

Посмотрите [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union).

Comment: Маленький вопрос по
template <class T>
class Name
{
//тело шаблона класса
};
Он же выглядеть должен так. Где здесь тело InputIt1, InputIt2?
А также private или public получится OutputIt?

Comment: Это вообще-то шаблон функции...